# Laravel Eloquent, not expected results from join

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a eloquent query like this:

```
    $entity= Entity::find($entity_id)
        ->join('address', 'entities.id', '=', 'address.entity_id');
    dd($entity);
```

Now when I go to url /entities/243

I get the results from ::find however I do not get results from my ->join, so there is no address.

When I do this query:

```
    $entity= Entity::where('id', $entity_id)
        ->join('address', 'entities.id', '=', 'address.entity_id')
        ->first();
```

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `entities` inner join `address` on `entities`.`id` = `address`.`entity_id` where `id` = 50 and `entities`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)

This is what I get, how would I structure this query properly? So I want to return entity that matches i.e and it's address, all within original array, I don't want it separate i.e

I want dd($entity); to give me:

entities fields: value
address fields: value

so I don't have to go $entity->address to get to address, hopefully that makes sense.

Edit::

//

```
  +"id": 43
  +"name": "Costa Coffee Town Hall"
  +"type": "Food & Drink"
  +"tags": "Coffee, Cake, Food"
  +"email": "cos@liveandnow.com"
  +"logo": "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/liveandnow-production/public/logo/1502795867.png"
  +"cover": ""
  +"bio": null
  +"main": null
  +"twitter_business": null
  +"facebook_business": null
  +"instagram_business": null
  +"google_places": null
  +"eventbrite": null
  +"featured": 1
  +"ical": null
  +"slug": null
  +"url": null
  +"video": null
  +"api_key": null
  +"contact_number": null
  +"contact_name": null
  +"geoloc_id": 142
  +"deleted_at": null
  +"created_at": "2017-07-27 16:08:12"
  +"updated_at": "2017-08-15 10:17:31"
  +"wikipedia": null
  +"building_name": "The Old Town Hall"
  +"address": "Parliament Square Greaves Street"
  +"town": "Oldham"
  +"postcode": "OL1 1QN"
  +"telephone": "0161 926 7706"
  +"private": 0
  +"entity_id": 142
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query with find() method should be like as follow:

```
$entity= Entity::leftJoin('address', 'entities.id', '=', 'address.entity_id')
               ->find($entity_id);
```

your query with first() method should be like as follow:

```
$entity= Entity::where('entities.id', $entity_id)
               ->leftJoin('address', 'entities.id', '=', 'address.entity_id')
               ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `entities.id` in where clause instead of `id`

Comment: I get 'null' as a result

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DB`. Try this:

```
 $entity= \DB::table('entities')
            ->where('entities.id', $entity_id)
            ->join('address', 'entities.id', '=', 'address.entity_id')
            ->first();
```

Comment: It gives me right address, but wrong entity? with id 43... also if address is empty, it's null which is wrong because entity is always there but address might be empty

Comment: In this case you can use leftJoin, so it would not return null.

Comment: Note that this does not return an entity. This will mix the two tables in the result.

Comment: how would I use leftJoin? still returns 'null'

Comment: I'm sorry, you should use right join in this case. I don't remember if there is a rightjoin function available. If there is not, you should switch the tables in the query to use leftjoin.